# Problems with translation

Tags: translation, korean-to-english

I have some problems to translate the following audio: [Soundcloud](https://soundcloud.com/user-180432189/korea-gdo19/s-7zNVh)

What I got from it is:

안녕하세요 맥스입니다 안타깝게도 저는 독일이 아니라 한국 여행중이에요. 북한아니라 남한이요 한국여행은 정말 즐거워요 이거 알아요? 4월14일 여기서 싱글을 위한 날이에요 이날 만약 싱글이면 검정색 국수를 먹어야한다고 하더라구요 왜냐하면 검정색은 슬픔을 나타내기 때문이죠 제가 그 국수를 먹었냐구요? 물론이죠 아주 맛있었어요 저는 그 국수를 제주도에서 먹었고 이제는 두번째먹었어요 아 이제 가야겠네요 버스가 오네요 행복한 부활절 휴가 보내세요

which translates to:

Hello, this is Max. Unfortunately I am traveling in Korea, not Germany. It's not North Korea, it's South Korea. It's really fun to travel to Korea. You know what: April 14th is the day for singles. I told you that if I had a single, I had to eat black noodles today, because the black color represents sadness. Did I eat the noodles? Yes, of course. It was very delicious. I ate it on Jeju Island and already for the second time. Oh, I have to go. Bus is coming. Happy Easter holiday.

(the actual translation was to german, the english version here is only provisionally)

However, I got negative feedback that the translation was quite inaccurate (not at all the style, but the meaning of the text, but not exactly *what*). Could anyone give me a hint, where I made a mistake?
The audio is spoken by a non-native korean, which makes it a bit difficult, but I thought I got everything relevant correctly...

Comment: 1) I heard that if I am a single (i.e., not having a girl friend), I had
to eat black noodles today. Because ... 2) I ate it on Jeju Island before and ate it again (so that
I have two experiences).

Comment: @HKLee Thank you, this is very kind of you. So, it seems I wasn't missing much? Did you get that from the audio? I wonder, what's the problem then. Thanks again!

Comment: @HKLee Ah, ok, these are two details which I got a bit wrong. IC. Maybe this was the problem, I will ask

Comment: There are slight things which can not be easily heard. But it is not
important in audio context. And I think that your listening is completely
correct (even though there is a few some minor things).

Comment: @HKLee Thank you very much! If you make it an answer, I would of course vote it up and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I heard that if I am a single (i.e., not having a girl friend), I
had to eat black noodles today.

2) 저는 그 국수를 제주도에서 먹었고 이제는 공지전 1번지로 가요. 아 이제 ...

I ate it on Jeju Island. And now I will go to 공지전 1번지(?) (maybe touring place). Ah, I have ...

3) 아 이제 가야겠어요 버스가 오네요 행복한 부활절 시간 보내세요

Oh, I have to go. Bus is coming (=The bus which I have to get in is
coming or tour bus is coming). Please, have a happy time at the day, Easter.

@부활절 (Easter) is not a holiday in Korea.

@ There are slight things which can not be easily heard. But it is
not important in audio context. And I think that your listening is
completely correct (even though there is a few some minor things).

@Here black noodle is 짜장면 Jjajangmyeon.

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Unfortunately, they still insist that one part is righteous wrong. I suspect, that the part with the "bus" is meant. Could there be any other meaning with regard to this part? I understand, that the speaking in the recording is very bad, please excuse.

Comment: Yes, I had a mistake. I modified.